# How to tell if React Native ListViewDataSource is empty?

Tags: react-native

I'm passing a `ListViewDataSource` down as a prop and want the child element to detect whether it's empty or not.

Debugging in Chrome, I see that the `_cachedRowCount` property is set to `0` when the list is empty.

Is there a better way to detect whether the list view is empty?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `getRowCount()`, for instance:

```
let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
let dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.rows || [])

console.log(dataSource.getRowCount())
```